# How to add images to a qualification test in Amazon Mechanical Turk command line tools?

Tags: xml, xslt, amazon-web-services, command-line, mechanicalturk

I am trying to add an external image URL to a Qualification Test using the Amazon Mechanical Turk command line tools. This requires editing the XML file titled "qualification.question" to include the image URL.

If I wanted to insert the URL http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Earth_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg into the code from the "qualification.question" below above the text "What is this a picture of?", how would I do this?

```
<Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>question1</QuestionIdentifier>
    <QuestionContent>
        <Text>What is this a picture of?</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
        <SelectionAnswer>
          <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
          <Selections>
            <Selection>
              <SelectionIdentifier>1a</SelectionIdentifier>
              <Text>Earth</Text>
            </Selection>
            <Selection>
              <SelectionIdentifier>1b</SelectionIdentifier>
              <Text>Sun</Text>
            </Selection>
          </Selections>
        </SelectionAnswer>
    </AnswerSpecification>
</Question>
```

Comment: so what's the error?

Comment: The error was "Value 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Earth_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '(http|https)://.*' for type 'URLType'.: But I see now what was wrong, and will update it and also edit my original post.

Answer (score 5):

Figured out how to do it. The updated code that has a question that shows an image is below.

```
#set( $image_url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Earth_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg" )
  <Question>
      <QuestionIdentifier>question1</QuestionIdentifier>
      <QuestionContent>
          <Binary>
            <MimeType>
              <Type>image</Type>
              <SubType>jpg</SubType>
            </MimeType>
            <DataURL>${image_url}</DataURL>
            <AltText>Image</AltText>
          </Binary>
          <Text>What is this a picture of?</Text>
      </QuestionContent>
      <AnswerSpecification>
          <SelectionAnswer>
            <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
            <Selections>
              <Selection>
                <SelectionIdentifier>1a</SelectionIdentifier>
                <Text>Earth</Text>
              </Selection>
              <Selection>
                <SelectionIdentifier>1b</SelectionIdentifier>
                <Text>Sun</Text>
              </Selection>
            </Selections>
          </SelectionAnswer>
      </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
```

Comment: That's great to answer your own question.

Comment: You probably want to add `<IsRequired>true</IsRequired>` within the `Question` element to require Workers make a selection before submitting the HIT. Without that, a Worker could accept and immediately submit, without choosing either option.